# Query Running 14 Days and Going- How to Optimize?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, dense-rank

I started this query 14 days ago, and it's still going. I REALLY don't think it should be taking this long, but I'm still pretty NOOB and not sure how to improve it. Do I stop it and make changes, or let it keep running? How would I improve it? The table is 550+mil rows x 6 columns it's processing.

**I HAVE:**

- MySQL 8.0.25
- Windows 10 (dedicated MySQL machine)
- AMD Ryzen 5 3600XT (6-Core)
- 128GB Ram
- Separate SSDs for both OS and Data Drives (fastest ssds available)

**THE QUERY:**

```
INSERT INTO t_stats_trades
        (ind, dir, o_dt, c_dt)
WITH CTE AS
        (SELECT IND, SIG, DT, 
         (DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(dt), DAYOFYEAR(dt), IND ORDER BY DT)-DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(dt), DAYOFYEAR(dt), IND, SIG ORDER BY DT)) GRP
          FROM t_stats_csv
        ORDER BY YEAR(dt), DAYOFYEAR(dt), IND, DT, SIG),
     CTE2 AS
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(dt), DAYOFYEAR(dt), IND ORDER BY IND) ROWNUM, IND, SIG, MIN(DT) START
          FROM CTE
          GROUP BY YEAR(dt), DAYOFYEAR(dt), IND, SIG, GRP
          ORDER BY YEAR(dt), DAYOFYEAR(dt), IND, START),
     cteSIG1 AS
    (SELECT ROWNUM, IND, SIG, START
      FROM CTE2
      WHERE SIG = 1
          ORDER BY IND, START),
     cteSIG3 AS
    (SELECT ROWNUM, IND, SIG, START
      FROM CTE2
      WHERE SIG = 3
      ORDER BY IND, START),
     cteS AS
    (SELECT J1.IND IND, "S" DIR, J1.START O_DT, J2.START C_DT
      FROM cteSIG1 J1
      JOIN cteSIG3 J2 ON J2.ROWNUM = J1.ROWNUM + 1
      WHERE DATE(J1.START) = DATE(J2.START)),
     cteL AS
    (SELECT J2.IND IND, "L" DIR, J2.START O_DT, J1.START C_DT
      FROM cteSIG1 J1
      JOIN cteSIG3 J2 ON J1.ROWNUM = J2.ROWNUM + 1
      WHERE DATE(J1.START) = DATE(J2.START))
SELECT IND, DIR, O_DT, C_DT
FROM  cteS
UNION ALL
SELECT IND, DIR, O_DT, C_DT
FROM  cteL
ORDER BY IND, DIR, O_DT
```

**SHOW CREATE TABLE:**

```
| t_stats_csv | CREATE TABLE `t_stats_csv` (
  `PK` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ind` varchar(18) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sig` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `cp` decimal(7,2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ind_sig_dt` (`ind`,`sig`,`dt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=500884006 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

**EXPLAIN:**

```
+----+--------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table          | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref   | rows      | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+--------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | INSERT       | t_stats_trades | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL  |      NULL |     NULL | NULL                            |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <derived4>     | NULL       | ref   | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 1       | const |        10 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <derived4>     | NULL       | ref   | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 1       | const |        10 |    10.00 | Using where                     |
|  4 | DERIVED      | <derived5>     | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL  | 495709464 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  5 | DERIVED      | t_stats_csv    | NULL       | index | NULL          | ind_sig_dt  | 80      | NULL  | 495709464 |   100.00 | Using index; Using filesort     |
|  9 | UNION        | <derived4>     | NULL       | ref   | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 1       | const |        10 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  9 | UNION        | <derived4>     | NULL       | ref   | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 1       | const |        10 |    10.00 | Using where                     |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,9>     | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL  |      NULL |     NULL | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+--------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

**EXPLAIN FORMAT=TREE:**

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| -> Insert into t_stats_trades
    -> Sort: IND, DIR, O_DT  (cost=2.50 rows=0)
        -> Table scan on <union temporary>  (cost=2.50 rows=0)
            -> Union materialize  (cost=52.50..52.50 rows=0)
                -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=25.00 rows=0)
                    -> Index lookup on CTE2 using <auto_key0> (SIG=1)
                        -> Materialize CTE cte2 if needed  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0)
                            -> Sort: `year(cte.DT)`, `dayofyear(cte.DT)`, cte.IND, `START`
                                -> Table scan on <temporary>  (cost=2.50..2.50 rows=0)
                                    -> Temporary table  (cost=2.50..2.50 rows=0)
                                        -> Window aggregate: row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY year(cte.DT),dayofyear(cte.DT),cte.IND ORDER BY cte.IND )
                                            -> Sort: `year(cte.DT)`, `dayofyear(cte.DT)`, cte.IND, cte.IND
                                                -> Table scan on <temporary>
                                                    -> Aggregate using temporary table
                                                        -> Table scan on CTE  (cost=2.50..2.50 rows=0)
                                                            -> Materialize CTE cte if needed  (cost=2.50..2.50 rows=0)
                                                                -> Sort: `year(t_stats_csv.dt)`, `dayofyear(t_stats_csv.dt)`, t_stats_csv.ind, t_stats_csv.dt, t_stats_csv.sig
                                                                    -> Table scan on <temporary>  (cost=2.50..2.50 rows=0)
                                                                        -> Temporary table  (cost=2.50..2.50 rows=0)
                                                                            -> Window aggregate: dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY year(t_stats_csv.dt),dayofyear(t_stats_csv.dt),t_stats_csv.ind,t_stats_csv.sig ORDER BY t_stats_csv.dt )
                                                                                -> Sort: `year(t_stats_csv.dt)`, `dayofyear(t_stats_csv.dt)`, t_stats_csv.ind, t_stats_csv.sig, t_stats_csv.dt
                                                                                    -> Table scan on <temporary>  (cost=2.50..2.50 rows=0)
                                                                                        -> Temporary table  (cost=2.50..2.50 rows=0)
                                                                                            -> Window aggregate: dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY year(t_stats_csv.dt),dayofyear(t_stats_csv.dt),t_stats_csv.ind ORDER BY t_stats_csv.dt )
                                                                                                -> Sort: year(t_stats_csv.dt), dayofyear(t_stats_csv.dt), t_stats_csv.ind, t_stats_csv.dt  (cost=51285505.65 rows=495709464)
                                                                                                    -> Index scan on t_stats_csv using ind_sig_dt
                    -> Filter: ((cast(cte2.`START` as date) = cast(cte2.`START` as date)) and (cte2.ROWNUM = (cte2.ROWNUM + 1)))  (cost=2.51..2.51 rows=1)
                        -> Index lookup on CTE2 using <auto_key0> (SIG=3)
                            -> Materialize CTE cte2 if needed (query plan printed elsewhere)  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0)
                -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=25.00 rows=0)
                    -> Index lookup on CTE2 using <auto_key0> (SIG=3)
                        -> Materialize CTE cte2 if needed (query plan printed elsewhere)  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0)
                    -> Filter: ((cast(cte2.`START` as date) = cast(cte2.`START` as date)) and (cte2.ROWNUM = (cte2.ROWNUM + 1)))  (cost=2.51..2.51 rows=1)
                        -> Index lookup on CTE2 using <auto_key0> (SIG=1)
                            -> Materialize CTE cte2 if needed (query plan printed elsewhere)  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0)
 |
```

**EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON:**

```
| {
  "query_block": {
    "union_result": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "table_name": "<union1,9>",
      "access_type": "ALL",
      "query_specifications": [
        {
          "dependent": false,
          "cacheable": true,
          "query_block": {
            "select_id": 1,
            "cost_info": {
              "query_cost": "38.50"
            },
            "table": {
              "insert": true,
              "table_name": "t_stats_trades",
              "access_type": "ALL"
            },
            "insert_from": {
              "nested_loop": [
                {
                  "table": {
                    "table_name": "CTE2",
                    "access_type": "ref",
                    "possible_keys": [
                      "<auto_key0>"
                    ],
                    "key": "<auto_key0>",
                    "used_key_parts": [
                      "SIG"
                    ],
                    "key_length": "1",
                    "ref": [
                      "const"
                    ],
                    "rows_examined_per_scan": 10,
                    "rows_produced_per_join": 10,
                    "filtered": "100.00",
                    "cost_info": {
                      "read_cost": "2.50",
                      "eval_cost": "1.00",
                      "prefix_cost": "3.50",
                      "data_read_per_join": "960"
                    },
                    "used_columns": [
                      "ROWNUM",
                      "IND",
                      "SIG",
                      "START"
                    ],
                    "materialized_from_subquery": {
                      "using_temporary_table": true,
                      "dependent": false,
                      "cacheable": true,
                      "query_block": {
                        "select_id": 4,
                        "cost_info": {
                          "query_cost": "551476781.20"
                        },
                        "ordering_operation": {
                          "using_filesort": true,
                          "windowing": {
                            "windows": [
                              {
                                "name": "<unnamed window>",
                                "using_temporary_table": true,
                                "using_filesort": true,
                                "filesort_key": [
                                  "year(`DT`)",
                                  "dayofyear(`DT`)",
                                  "`IND`",
                                  "`IND`"
                                ],
                                "functions": [
                                  "row_number"
                                ]
                              }
                            ],
                            "cost_info": {
                              "sort_cost": "495709464.00"
                            },
                            "grouping_operation": {
                              "using_temporary_table": true,
                              "using_filesort": false,
                              "table": {
                                "table_name": "CTE",
                                "access_type": "ALL",
                                "rows_examined_per_scan": 495709464,
                                "rows_produced_per_join": 495709464,
                                "filtered": "100.00",
                                "cost_info": {
                                  "read_cost": "6196370.80",
                                  "eval_cost": "49570946.40",
                                  "prefix_cost": "55767317.20",
                                  "data_read_per_join": "44G"
                                },
                                "used_columns": [
                                  "IND",
                                  "SIG",
                                  "DT",
                                  "GRP"
                                ],
                                "materialized_from_subquery": {
                                  "using_temporary_table": true,
                                  "dependent": false,
                                  "cacheable": true,
                                  "query_block": {
                                    "select_id": 5,
                                    "cost_info": {
                                      "query_cost": "1538413897.65"
                                    },
                                    "ordering_operation": {
                                      "using_filesort": true,
                                      "cost_info": {
                                        "sort_cost": "495709464.00"
                                      },
                                      "windowing": {
                                        "windows": [
                                          {
                                            "name": "<unnamed window>",
                                            "definition_position": 1,
                                            "using_temporary_table": true,
                                            "using_filesort": true,
                                            "filesort_key": [
                                              "year(`dt`)",
                                              "dayofyear(`dt`)",
                                              "`ind`",
                                              "`dt`"
                                            ],
                                            "functions": [
                                              "dense_rank"
                                            ]
                                          },
                                          {
                                            "name": "<unnamed window>",
                                            "definition_position": 2,
                                            "last_executed_window": true,
                                            "using_temporary_table": true,
                                            "using_filesort": true,
                                            "filesort_key": [
                                              "year(`dt`)",
                                              "dayofyear(`dt`)",
                                              "`ind`",
                                              "`sig`",
                                              "`dt`"
                                            ],
                                            "functions": [
                                              "dense_rank"
                                            ]
                                          }
                                        ],
                                        "cost_info": {
                                          "sort_cost": "991418928.00"
                                        },
                                        "table": {
                                          "table_name": "t_stats_csv",
                                          "access_type": "index",
                                          "key": "ind_sig_dt",
                                          "used_key_parts": [
                                            "ind",
                                            "sig",
                                            "dt"
                                          ],
                                          "key_length": "80",
                                          "rows_examined_per_scan": 495709464,
                                          "rows_produced_per_join": 495709464,
                                          "filtered": "100.00",
                                          "using_index": true,
                                          "cost_info": {
                                            "read_cost": "1714559.25",
                                            "eval_cost": "49570946.40",
                                            "prefix_cost": "51285505.65",
                                            "data_read_per_join": "44G"
                                          },
                                          "used_columns": [
                                            "PK",
                                            "ind",
                                            "sig",
                                            "dt"
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "table": {
                    "table_name": "CTE2",
                    "access_type": "ref",
                    "possible_keys": [
                      "<auto_key0>"
                    ],
                    "key": "<auto_key0>",
                    "used_key_parts": [
                      "SIG"
                    ],
                    "key_length": "1",
                    "ref": [
                      "const"
                    ],
                    "rows_examined_per_scan": 10,
                    "rows_produced_per_join": 10,
                    "filtered": "10.00",
                    "cost_info": {
                      "read_cost": "25.00",
                      "eval_cost": "1.00",
                      "prefix_cost": "38.50",
                      "data_read_per_join": "960"
                    },
                    "used_columns": [
                      "ROWNUM",
                      "IND",
                      "SIG",
                      "START"
                    ],
                    "attached_condition": "((cast(`cte2`.`START` as date) = cast(`cte2`.`START` as date)) and (`cte2`.`ROWNUM` = (`cte2`.`ROWNUM` + 1)))",
                    "materialized_from_subquery": {
                      "sharing_temporary_table_with": {
                        "select_id": 4
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "dependent": false,
          "cacheable": true,
          "query_block": {
            "select_id": 9,
            "cost_info": {
              "query_cost": "38.50"
            },
            "nested_loop": [
              {
                "table": {
                  "table_name": "CTE2",
                  "access_type": "ref",
                  "possible_keys": [
                    "<auto_key0>"
                  ],
                  "key": "<auto_key0>",
                  "used_key_parts": [
                    "SIG"
                  ],
                  "key_length": "1",
                  "ref": [
                    "const"
                  ],
                  "rows_examined_per_scan": 10,
                  "rows_produced_per_join": 10,
                  "filtered": "100.00",
                  "cost_info": {
                    "read_cost": "2.50",
                    "eval_cost": "1.00",
                    "prefix_cost": "3.50",
                    "data_read_per_join": "960"
                  },
                  "used_columns": [
                    "ROWNUM",
                    "IND",
                    "SIG",
                    "START"
                  ],
                  "materialized_from_subquery": {
                    "sharing_temporary_table_with": {
                      "select_id": 4
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "table": {
                  "table_name": "CTE2",
                  "access_type": "ref",
                  "possible_keys": [
                    "<auto_key0>"
                  ],
                  "key": "<auto_key0>",
                  "used_key_parts": [
                    "SIG"
                  ],
                  "key_length": "1",
                  "ref": [
                    "const"
                  ],
                  "rows_examined_per_scan": 10,
                  "rows_produced_per_join": 10,
                  "filtered": "10.00",
                  "cost_info": {
                    "read_cost": "25.00",
                    "eval_cost": "1.00",
                    "prefix_cost": "38.50",
                    "data_read_per_join": "960"
                  },
                  "used_columns": [
                    "ROWNUM",
                    "IND",
                    "SIG",
                    "START"
                  ],
                  "attached_condition": "((cast(`cte2`.`START` as date) = cast(`cte2`.`START` as date)) and (`cte2`.`ROWNUM` = (`cte2`.`ROWNUM` + 1)))",
                  "materialized_from_subquery": {
                    "sharing_temporary_table_with": {
                      "select_id": 4
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
} |
```

** UPDATE **
This is a continuation of the question I asked [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67876852/edit)

**WHAT I HAVE (data generated from a query below):**

```
| ID     | IND | SIG | START               |
|--------|-----|----:|---------------------|
| 1      | atr |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:05:00 |
| 2      | atr |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:16:00 |
| 3      | atr |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:17:00 |
| 4      | atr |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:26:00 |
| 5      | ema |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:07:00 |
| 6      | ema |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:09:00 |
| 7      | ema |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:10:00 |
| 8      | ema |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:18:00 |
| 9      | ema |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:20:00 |
| 10     | ema |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:27:00 |
| 11     | ema |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:29:00 |
| 12     | tig |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:12:00 |
| 13     | tig |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:13:00 |
| 14     | tig |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:14:00 |
| 15     | tig |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:15:00 |
| 16     | tig |   3 | 2018-09-04 11:23:00 |
| 17     | tig |   1 | 2018-09-04 11:28:00 |
```

**WHAT I NEED:**

```
| IND | START ID | START SIG | START DT            | END ID | END SIG | END DT              |
|-----|----------|----------:|---------------------|--------|---------|---------------------|
| atr | 1        |         1 | 2018-09-04 11:05:00 | 2      | 3       | 2018-09-04 11:16:00 |
| atr | 3        |         1 | 2018-09-04 11:17:00 | 4      | 3       | 2018-09-04 11:26:00 |
| ema | 6        |         1 | 2018-09-04 11:09:00 | 7      | 3       | 2018-09-04 11:10:00 |
| ema | 8        |         1 | 2018-09-04 11:18:00 | 9      | 3       | 2018-09-04 11:20:00 |
| ema | 10       |         1 | 2018-09-04 11:27:00 | 11     | 3       | 2018-09-04 11:29:00 |
| tig | 13       |         1 | 2018-09-04 11:13:00 | 14     | 3       | 2018-09-04 11:14:00 |
| tig | 15       |         1 | 2018-09-04 11:15:00 | 16     | 3       | 2018-09-04 11:23:00 |
```

**DETAILS:**

I need help (transposing?) every other row of generated data from a     query (thanks @Strawberry!) Basically for every id where SIG = 1 with    the same IND, I need the earliest ID/DATE where SIG = 3.

Each IND grouping and the start/finish combo must start with SIG = 1,    and FINISH w/ SIG = 3 within the same row.

Missing ID's #5, 12, 17 are due to not following the above point (ie- the grouping might have started with 3 as the earliest date, or     ended on a 1 so those rows are eliminated from the results).

Data is over 550+mil rows, so the query needs to be efficient. I'm not sure if the original query can be re-written to reflect what's needed, or, if I keep the original query and add to it to manipulate the output into the new format?

Comment: What is the goal of the query?

Comment: Hi @RickJames - thanks for your reply, as always. I updated the bottom of the post with full details/data. You've helped me get to this point- any other ideas on how to speed this up? It's still running!  Thank you!

Comment: id=5 and 12 are deliberately ignored?  Is there anything else other than pairs of rows with SIG=1, then 3?

Comment: Stop it and start over. Two weeks is too long. One thing jumps out at me: Your use of `YEAR(dt), DAYOFYEAR(dt)` to uniquely identify each date. You can just use `DATE(dt)` and you'll get a simpler expression. Then, work hard on the indexes and execution plan for your first `CTE`.  You may also want to consider a [stored generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) for `DATE(dt)` that's indexed well enough to [cover](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index) that first CTE. And troubleshoot with a subset of data.

Comment: @RickJames Correct. I actually need 2 different pairs as you can see from the final union- (1, 3) and (3, 1). For the (1, 3) pairs, I need the first 1 and then skip any additional 1's until it gets to the first 3 (chronologically) and uses that. Then I need the next 1 after that pair and find the earliest 3 after that, and so on. Then same thing with the (3, 1) pair, again ignoring any repeated 3s before finding the matching 1. Let me know if that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @RickJames This is for testing stock trading positions based on various indicators/patters on a chart. sig=1 means the indicator is going down, 3 means going up. So I'm trying to take all the signals and put them into 'trades' (or the pairs) of entry/exit positions. So I want to find every trade where the sig=1 (entry) and then sig=3 (exit) so I can then subtract the 2 later and see a profit/loss. Then I would find all the reverse pairs so sig=3 is the entry, and sig=1 is the exit. Sometimes there's a repeat of the entry sig before it gives the exit sig, so that is skipped. Hope that helps!

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you for the reply. I saw the same thing on the Date(dt)- but read somewhere that using Date() is horrible on performance, and to break it up? I also partitioned on those as I thought that speeds it all up? I'm also confused as I thought the index I have IS correct to cover what is needed. I really don't understand how to read the EXPLAINs to make changes (after hours of videos/blogs trying to learn)- any suggestions more specific on that? I'll look at the stored generated column thing. Thank you!

Comment: @user3718843 - Splitting it into `YEAR()` and `DAYOFYEAR()` is probably worse.  The issue with either is "sargeability" and how that interferes with using any `INDEX`.  `PARTITIONing` is rarely useful for speed.  (We can discuss the details if you like.)  Yeah, `EXPLAIN` is cryptic.  O.Jones gives a clearer suggestion of what to do next.

Comment: @O.Jones Didn't know generated columns existed- mind blown! However, I'm not quite seeing how creating a stored generated column for the Date field would help me at all? The 1st CTE just pulls the date (dt) from the already existing col/table into the CTE and uses that for the Dense Rank/Order By... can you explain how I would use this to my advantage? Thank you!

Comment: @RickJames I would love to hear more about sageability, Indexing and Partitions in terms of speed. Ive read quite a bit that says partitioning dramatically increases speed- so that's why I have the Year/Date partitions in there... I look forward to learning more! Thank you

Comment: @O.Jones actually, I read up on sargeability, and see that in the later CTE's, I'm using a function(field) in the where statements (WHERE DATE(J1.START) = DATE(J2.START)). If I create a generated col for the Date(dt) that should help keep it all within the index. Additionally perhaps I eliminate the date partitions all together from the getgo- let me know if I'm on the right track. Thank you!

Comment: You can refactor a `DATE()` to `DATE()` comparison into a possibly sargeable range match on one of the two datetime columns.  `a.dt >= DATE(b.dt) AND a.dt > DATE(b.dt) +INTERVAL 1 DAY`. (Mind the `<` in the end-of-range condition.)

Comment: @user3718843 - A generated column can be indexed once, up front.  A CTE using `DATE(dt)` either can't be indexed or must do it on the fly.

Comment: @user3718843 - A general rule in using indexes:  `=` (eg, `date = 'constant'`) is more optimizable than a range (eg, `dt >= 'constant' AND dt < 'constant' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`)

Comment: @user3718843 - [_INDEX cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) and [_PARTITIONing_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).  The keyword `PARTITION` has 2 meanings; with `OVER` it is similar to `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @user3718843 - Be aware that the "generated" column for `DATE(dt)` can be "virtual" and still indexed.  This will avoid inflating the table further (but will add disk space for the secondary index).  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there may be other tips, especially with respect to "composite" indexes.

Comment: @RickJames I included the Create Table in the original post. I added a stored generated column for DATE(dt)- it's still running after 16.5hrs. Once complete I'll drop/re-create the composite index. My plan was to re-create it in this order: dtonly (this is the new stored column), ind, dt, sig. Thoughts on doing this and in this order? Also is it normal for the adding stored col to be 16+hrs? Thank you!

Comment: @user3718843 - I added (to my Answer) some thoughts on `INDEXing`.  Please provide the new `CREATE TABLE` and the revised `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing your other two similar questions, I think this is not going to be practical in SQL.  Suggest you write application code to process one 'day'.  Use SQL to extract that chunk of the data.  (I assume there is no spillage from one day to the next.)

To further speed it up, you could have multiple threads, each doing one such chunk.  It would probably be counter-productive to have more than twice as many threads as you have CPU cores.

Once you have caught up, set up a cron job to process yesterday's data at night.

Then...  Rethink the schema you currently have.  I *think* (but am not sure), it would be easier/simpler to start a wider row with each new SIG=1.  Leave NULLs in the SIG=3 columns for the time being.  When the next entry for that ticker comes in, fetch the latest row and decide whether to augment it or toss the new row.  This would be a rather short *transaction*; it would promptly update your new table.

There may be some rows thus created that are incomplete (NULL in some columns, but no hope of filling them in); deal with them when fetching rows -- either keep those rows or filter them out (`WHERE ... IS NOT NULL`).

After adding code to produce the new format on the fly, consider whether to keep the 'raw' data (`t_stats_csv`).

Moral of the story:  Sometimes it is best to use a different programming language (other than SQL) for a task.

**Indexes**

(Assuming you are replacing `YEAR(dt), DAYOFYEAR(dt)` by `just_date`:)

I think the only place where indexes are useful might be here:

```
(DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY just_date,
      IND ORDER BY DT) - 
 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY just_date,
      IND, SIG ORDER BY DT)) GRP
    FROM t_stats_csv
        ORDER BY just_date, IND, DT, SIG
```

These indexes may be useful:

```
INDEX(just_date, ind, sig, dt)
INDEX(just_date, ind, dt, sig)
```

Think about whether that code really needs `sig` before `dt` in one case and the opposite order in the other case.

Elsewhere, this might be useful (but I am not sure):

```
INDEX(sig, ind, start)
```

Which brings up the question of whether `start` is a `DATETIME` but you need just the `DATE` in some cases.

Comment: Yes, the longer term goal is to keep ongoing/updated daily data. However, right now I'm just trying to run some statistics on each strategy, and see if it's feasible to move forward with ongoing tracking. None of this will be used for real-time data- merely keeping ongoing statistics on overall strategies. 

Any suggestions on where to look/learn about using threading? Do I just run separate queries on different parts of the data at the same time? 

Definitely some great ideas here- I really appreciate your input, and your blog, btw! I've learned a ton from you already. :)

Comment: @user3718843 - I can't tell whether the CTEs are being terribly inefficient.  I don't see an easy way to do the query by some other means.  As for multiple queries running at once, be sure to have a suitable `WHERE` and `INDEX`, such as `INDEX(dt)` with `WHERE dt >= '2020-11-11' AND dt < '2020-11-11' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`.